# pykcharts scatter example does not work with local file

Tags: d3.js, visualization, pykcharts

I am using the following pykcahrts example

```
<head> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pykcharts.1.1.0.min.css">
  <script src="pykcharts.1.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="my_chart"></div>
  <script>
   window.PykChartsInit = function (e) {
   var k = new PykCharts.multiD.scatter({

      //Chart Container Id
      "selector": "#my_chart",

      //Data file path
      "data": "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/chartstore.io-data/scatter.csv",

      //Chart mode
      "mode": "default",

      //Chart Size Parameters
      "chart_width": 620,
      "chart_height": 400,
      "chart_margin_left": 50,
      "chart_margin_right": 25,
      "chart_margin_top": 35,
      "chart_margin_bottom": 35,

      //Chart color parameters
      "chart_color": [ 
         "#255aee",
         "#517bf1",
         "#7c9cf5",
         "#a8bdf8"
      ],

      //X-Axis parameters
      "axis_x_enable": "yes",
      "axis_x_title": "",
      "axis_x_position": "bottom",
      "axis_x_pointer_position": "bottom",
      "axis_x_line_color": "#1D1D1D",
      "axis_x_pointer_size": 12,
      "axis_x_pointer_color": "#1D1D1D",
      "axis_x_no_of_axis_value": 5,
      "axis_x_pointer_padding": 6,
      "axis_x_outer_pointer_length": 0,
      "axis_x_pointer_values": [],
      "axis_x_time_value_datatype": "",
      "axis_x_time_value_interval": 0,

      //Y-Axis parameters
      "axis_y_enable": "yes",
      "axis_y_title": "",
      "axis_y_position": "left",
      "axis_y_pointer_position": "left",
      "axis_y_line_color": "#1D1D1D",
      "axis_y_pointer_size": 12,
      "axis_y_pointer_color": "#1D1D1D",
      "axis_y_no_of_axis_value": 5,
      "axis_y_pointer_padding": 6,
      "axis_y_pointer_values": [],
      "axis_y_outer_pointer_length": 0,
      "axis_y_time_value_datatype": "",
      "axis_y_time_value_interval": 0,

      //Chart labels parameters
      "label_size": 13,
      "label_weight": "normal",
      "label_family": "Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif",

      //Realtime data parameters
      "real_time_charts_last_updated_at_enable": "no",
      "real_time_charts_refresh_frequency": 0,

      //chart border parameters
      "border_between_chart_elements_thickness": 1,
      "border_between_chart_elements_style": "solid",

      //Chart-interactive parameters
      "chart_onhover_highlight_enable": "yes",
      "tooltip_enable": "yes",
      "transition_duration": 0,

      //Chart legends parameters
      "legends_enable": "yes",
      "legends_display": "horizontal",
      "legends_text_weight": "normal",
      "legends_text_family": "Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif",

      //Scatter parameters
      "scatterplot_pointer_enable": "no",
      "scatterplot_radius": 20,
      "variable_circle_size_enable": "yes",
      "zoom_enable": "no",

      //Chart title parameters
      "title_text": "Enter title here",
      "title_size": 2,
      "title_weight": "bold",
      "title_family": "Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif",
      "title_color": "#1D1D1D",

      //Chart subtitle parameters
      "subtitle_text": "Enter subtitle here",
      "subtitle_size": 1,
      "subtitle_weight": "normal",
      "subtitle_family": "Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif",
      "subtitle_color": "black",

      //Credits parameters
      "credit_my_site_name": "PykCharts",
      "credit_my_site_url": "http://pykcharts.com"
   });
   k.execute();
  }
   </script>
</body>
```

If i change `"data": "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/chartstore.io-data/scatter.csv",` to `scatter.csv` where the local file is literally the web file saved locally the plot does not appear.

has anyone experienced this?

any insight?

Comment: No error. It just doesnt load.

Comment: My question was misleading slightly. i edited.

Comment: Can you please check whether the downloaded file has access permissions? You can use "chmod 644 scatter.csv" to set the appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me:

I was using chrome and the library was not working on the local file.

I tried firefox and it works perfectly.

Comment: That could be because of some strict security settings in chrome.

Comment: Maybe due to cross-origin policy